# Android - Black Screen after clicking BACK in an Activity with an AltertDialog after Search Activity

Tags: java, android

I have an Activity which displays an alert dialog priot to the content.
Also a search activity is called before this activity.

Now when i press back on this activity i am lead to a black screen (which i assume is eighter because of the dialog [unlikely] or from the search activity). Only when i press BACK twice i get to the activity i was before.

How can i get rid of this?

Thank you.

Comment: Show the part of the code which causing the problem.

Comment: Are you running something on UI thread that prevents UI refresh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This phenomenon was caused by the search activity. to avoid this i simply added `android:noHistory="true"` for the Search Activity in the Manifest.